# ssh tunneling to a vhost subdomain

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to use ssh tunneling to forward localhost to a specific (vhost) subdomain?

In other words, I have the following domain/subdomain, both are on the same IP

- `domain.dev`
- `vhost.domain.dev`

On the remote machine, I updated the `/etc/hosts` to include the IP for both

```
# Remote machine /etc/hosts
# <...snip...>
1.2.3.4 domain.dev vhost.domain.dev
```

but when I try both of these commands

- `ssh -L 8080:vhost.domain.dev user@remote`
- `ssh -L 8080:domain.dev user@remote`

In both these cases, I can only access `domain.dev` but not `vhost.domain.dev` (on `localhost:8080`)

Is there anyway I can access/tunnel the requests through the remote machine? sadly I cannot use VPN to be part of the same network where I can access `domain.dev` and `domain.dev` is only accessible through the remote machine (network)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use /etc/hosts on your own machine (pointing both domains at one of the localhost IP addresses).

It's not something you can achieve with just SSH, because the domain name isn't sent at TCP level at all – it's sent at the HTTP level, by your browser.

Meanwhile, the tunnel (i.e. your `-L` option) can just point directly to the IP address: it won't make any difference to TCP, which only deals with IP addresses either way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ssh proxy and configure the browser/system to use this proxy using

```
ssh -D 8080 user@remote
```

one thing to note, make sure that you do DNS lookup remotely
for example in Firefor `about:config` make sure `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` is set to true (otherwise firefox will try to lookup the domain locally, instead of on the remote machine)

and some tools won't work (ex. curl won't work locally but works correctly on remote machine anyway)